# override bound value of progressbar with a setter in xaml/wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, progress-bar

I have the following XAML

```
<ProgressBar Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,1" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Progress}">
    <ProgressBar.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DidAllServicesRestart}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkRed"/>
                    <Setter Property="Value" Value="100"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ProgressBar.Resources>
</ProgressBar>
```

The DataTrigger works great for setting Foreground to DarkRed, but setting the value of the progressbar to 100 does not work. I'm guessing because the {Binding Progress} overrides it?

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that the `{Binding Progress}` overrides it.  In the [Dependency Property order of precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx), the local value has the 3rd highest priority, whereas the style triggers are 6th.

> 3) **Local value.** A local value might be set through the convenience of the "wrapper" property, which also equates to setting as an attribute or property element in XAML, or by a call to the SetValue API using a property of a specific instance. If you set a local value by using a binding or a resource, these each act in the precedence as if a direct value was set.
>
> ....
>
> 6) **Style triggers.** The triggers within styles from page or application (these styles might be either explicit or implicit styles, but not from the default styles, which have lower precedence).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, do you know what a good/common solution to this would be?

Comment: @user45763 It depends ... are you just trying to set the default/initial value?  If so, then a good solution would be to set `Progress=100` in your view model.